# How can I prevent default deselection of an highlighted text on click of an input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my AngularJS web app, users can select and highlight text. However, when they click on the input box to add labels, the highlighted text gets deselected. I tried using event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation(), but it didn't work. How can I prevent the deselection of highlighted text when clicking on the input box? Here's the code:

```
<!-- Text element -->
<p class="highlighted-text" ng-class="{'highlighted': isHighlighted}" ng-mouseup="toggleHighlight()">{{transcription}}</p>

<!-- Input box -->
<input type="text" ng-model="newLabel" ng-focus="preventDeselect(true)" ng-blur="preventDeselect(false)">

<!-- controller -->
$scope.isHighlighted = false;

$scope.toggleHighlight = function() {
  $scope.isHighlighted = !$scope.isHighlighted;
};

$scope.preventDeselect = function(selected) {
  if (selected) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
};
```